# How do I show a certain field is ordered.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis, field-theory

I have $F={(x∈ℝ||x=a+b\sqrt{2}}$ where a,b ∈ Q.) I basically need to deduce that this is an ordered field and I have no idea how. I've already proved that from any two x,y in F that xy and x+y are also in F. And that if x is in F and x doesn't equal zero then $1/x$ is also in x, if that's of any help.

My book gives this definition for ordered fields.
A field F is said to be an ordered field if F is also an ordered set such that:

(i) For x, y,z ∈ F, x < y implies x+z < y+z.

(ii) For x, y ∈ F, x > 0 and y > 0 implies xy > 0.

Comment: How do you define "ordered field"?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that $\mathbb R$ is an ordered field, and that  $F$ is contained in R?

Comment: I think I would be allowed to use that R is an ordered field.

Comment: The definition my book gives is :                                                                                "A field F is said to be an ordered field if F is also an ordered set such that:
(i) For x, y,z ∈ F, x < y implies x+z < y+z.
(ii) For x, y ∈ F, x > 0 and y > 0 implies xy > 0.
"

Comment: you have used   capital $F$ twice.  The usual question in this area  would use   $F={(x∈ℝ||x=a+b\sqrt{2}}$ where $a,b\in \mathbb Q.)$

Comment: Yeah the ordered part should be covered by the properties of $<$ in $\mathbb R,$ if you can show that $F$ is a field then that should suffice

Comment: the easier definition of ordered is to say there is a subset $P$ of the field to be called the positive numbers, there is trichotomy, for any $x$ exactly one of $x=0, x \in P, -x \in P.$ Then the product or sum of two positive  field elements must also be positive.  Over the rationals, you still need to show closure: easy enough to show sum and product, also difference, reciprocal needs work.

Comment: Well, would I have to literally just go through every field axiom and prove each one then, to show it's a field?

Answer (score 0):

You define $F = \{a + b\sqrt2 \mid a,b \in F\}$. This does not make sense, you probably mean
$$F = \{a + b\sqrt2 \mid a,b \in \mathbb Q \} .$$
You have to show that $F$ is a *subfield of $\mathbb R$* which means that is a field with respect to the operations "$+$" and "$\cdot$" of $\mathbb R$. You can do this by checking all axioms or by using the following lemma:

$F$ is a subfield iff it has the following properties:

1. $0, 1 \in F$.
2. $x + y \in F$ for all $x,y \in F$.
3. $-x \in F$ for all $x \in F$.
4. $x \cdot y \in F$ for all $x,y \in F$.
5. $1/x \in F$ for all $x \in F \setminus \{0\}$.

I shall not prove this lemma here, but in short it is true because all field axioms are satisfied in $\mathbb R \supset F$ and $F$ is closed with to the operations "$+$" and "$\cdot$".

Each subfield of an ordered field is itself ordered with respect to the order inherited from the original field. This is true because (i) and (ii) trivially remain valid when restricted to elements of the subfield.

Comment: yeah, I did mean Q, I wrote that wrong. Thank you.