# Defining a positive subset in a field

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K:=\left\{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}$. How to define a subset $P$ in $K$ such that $P$ is positive.

I'm lost with this question. With my professor I saw that we can define this $P$ in $\Bbb R$: $a\leq b\iff b-a\in P$. Also, for every $r\in \Bbb R$, only one of the following satisfies that $a\in P, a=0, -a\in P$.

Now, how could I extrapolate this into the field $K$. If I'm not mistaken I should check when does
$\alpha=a+b\sqrt{2}\in K$ is positive. Indeed,
$$\alpha > 0 \iff b>-\frac{a}{\sqrt 2}$$
but it seems like it doesn't help since we have two variables $a,b$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: If both $a,b$ are positive rationals then $a+b \sqrt 2$ is also positive; note that $1$ and $ \sqrt 2$  are called positive.  If both are negative so is $a + b \sqrt 2 $  special cases if either is zero. Finally, if $ab < 0,$  find the rational number $a^2 - 2 b^2$ which is either positive or negative....

Comment: Why is important the case when $ab<0$? @WillJagy

Comment: write it this way: both $s,t > 0,$  we want to be sure about $s - t \sqrt 2.$  Well,   here I made $s + t \sqrt 2$ positive.  Thus, $(s - t \sqrt 2)(s+t \sqrt 2) = s^2 - 2 t^2$ is the same as  $s - t \sqrt 2.$ Beyond that, I don't have your book or course notes.

Comment: Is this related to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4543229?